# What can I say in Github issues?

Tags: github

I'm new to the open source community. When I look at projects on Github I don't see any "forum". There's only an "issues" page. Is that only meant for submitting bugs? Or can I say other things? for example:

1. Can I suggest features? e.g. "I have an idea. It would be great if this project had this and that."
2. Can I ask questions like "How does this work?" or "What's the syntax for this?"
3. Is it nice to address problems that I'm having? e.g. "I tried this but it didn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Can someone help me?"
4. Can I ask what the owners think about a pull request I want to send? e.g "I'm going to implement this. Would you accept it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to all but check to see if there is a better place for 2 and 3.

StackOverflow should be your first port of call, first to check if your question has been asked and second to construct a question.

1 and 4 are most certainly the sort of things you can create an issue for. The maintainers are likely to tag them as 'Feature request' or 'Improvement' etc.